# How do I map a specific URL/Regex in NGINX to a proxy address

Tags: nginx

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy for a Grafana server which is connected to Elasticsearch.  Elasticsearch is not publicly accessible (currently) but I would like to have a link from Grafana to a specific document.

Currently, I have the following block:

```
 location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            ...
 }
```

And I would like to add another URL that would proxy from `/id/1234` to the url `http://localhost:9200/myindex/_doc/1234`.  But I only want it to be if the id is an integer.

How would I do that?

Comment: `location ~ ^/id/[0-9]+` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integer `id` you will need to capture it using a *regular expression* `location` and pass it to the `proxy_pass` directive as a variable.

For example:

```
location ~ /id/([0-9]+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/myindex/_doc/$1;
}
```